# Why does my Eclipse "count objects" before pushing upstream to GIT each time

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, egit

Every time I push a commit to upstream Git using Eclipse, it keeps counting thousands of objects. This happens even if I just commit a single line change. And it takes about 5-10 minutes.

[image: Screenshot showing "Counting" of thousands of objects]

Why does Eclipse do this? Is there some configuration option I have selected which makes this happen? How could I stop this from happening? This step is not happening for my colleagues who check-in to the same remote repository.

Comment: Did you find out? I have the same problem.

Comment: No I didn't find any solution! But, I have since moved on from that project. So, haven't faced it again. But, it remained an issue with that Eclipse app and git repo combination as long as I was using it.

Answer (score 2):

A good workaround for this issue is to select the "Run in background" button.  Upon sending the push branch job to the background, the job will finish almost immediately in my experience.  It appears that the process of writing the count to the screen is what is slowing down the performance of the job.

Comment: Sounds like a possible solution. Although I have moved on to a difference machine now!

Comment: This worked for me, although I don't know why start appearing that message...

Answer (score 0):

Not only in eclipse, even pushing using git push does these things and prints other stats.

This is just the output of the git command git count-objects -v for the push (the same command is called for output when gc, pull and clone). More info in the man pages : git-count-objects(1).

```
$ git count-objects -v
...
size: 14 # The "Compressing objects: 100% (14/14)" part (the size in KiB)
in-pack: 22 # The "Counting objects: 22" part (the number of objects)
...
```

Why does git push counts objects ?

Every thing in git is represented by objects . This helps in the mechanism between the local and remote to talk what has what and what things has to be passed on .

Comment: I can understand some amount of counting is involved. Although, for me it takes a few minutes and shows progress counting 20,000+ objects, whereas for my colleague it would take few seconds. Is there some mode where it re-evaluates every single file during each push?

Comment: It depending on the size of the commit . And I am unable to comment of the process eclipse do when you push from eclipse . But use the command  "git count-objects -v " to check what is different between you colleague and you machine .

Answer (score 0):

Try running an update on eGit, as it looks like it might be a known bug, which has been fixed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516276

But the update is not yet generally available so you'll need to update to EGit nightly http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly/ or just run pushes in the background for now, per the advice at the end of this page:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1085518/